# Nest.js deployment to now.sh

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, vercel

I am currently trying to deploy my demo application to [zeit now.sh](https://zeit.co). In [documentation](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/official-builders/node-js-server-now-node-server/) I have found how I can deploy Node.js and Express.js application. But example that I am referring expects as parameter js file with server initialization, and by default Nest.js project has as entry point ts file. Whole application is written in typescript. If I try to use `main.ts` as entry point, I am getting this  error:

```
11/28 08:05 PM (1m)

{ Error: Cannot find module './app.module'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:26040:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:21:30)
    at Module.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:26050:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:21:30)
    at module.exports.Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:85:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:88:10) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

11/28 08:05 PM (1m)

Error while initializing entrypoint: { Error: Cannot find module './app.module'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:26040:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:21:30)
    at Module.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:26050:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:21:30)
    at module.exports.Object.setPrototypeOf.__proto__ (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:85:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/user/src/main.ts:88:10) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Is there anybody that have experience with deployment of Nest.js app to now.sh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Add the file `now.json` to your project root directory:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/main.js",
      "use": "@now/node-server"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/main.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

2) Run `npm run build` to compile your project to the dist folder

3) Run `now` (the cli) to deploy your project

Comment: with this conf :
NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_LAMBDA

Comment: the same as for @MuhammedMoussa