# What is the right way of production deployment of nestjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, deployment, nestjs

I've developed simple nestjs rest services. Now I am planning to deploy my app. Please help me with efficient way of production deployment of nestjs app.

Comment: Hi! Could you give more details about what you're expecting as answer/advices? The process of deployment of a Nestjs app is very similar to any nodejs app, even if I'd recommend compiling your source code before starting the app (and not using ts-node, just like in the standard development mode), with a well defined `tsconfig.json` dedicated to production releases (do not emit the source maps unless you have a good reason, same for the declarations, strip comments, etc)

Comment: Am expecting a good guide article/answer on how to. Or sample of production ready tsconfig.json with webpack tool.

Answer (score 25):

## Own server

1) Checkout your project's repository on your server and run `npm install`.

2) Run `npm run build` which compiles your project to javascript:

```
rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig.build.json
```

3) Start your application with:

```
node dist/main.js
```

## Serverless

#### zeit now

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54958641/4694994).

#### Heroku

1) Add the file `Procfile` to your project's root directory:

```
web: npm run start:prod
```

2) Add this line to your `package.json`'s `scripts`:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "echo Skip builds on Heroku"
```

3) Set the port in your `main.ts` (or in your `ConfigService`)

```
await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: I have run `npm run build` and system create a folder named `dist`. But when I execute `node dist/main.js`, the cmd shows `Error: Cannot find module 'src/article/article.entity'`. In develop mode it's normal.

Comment: @Eve NestJS can't handle absolute paths like this by default. Replace it with a relative path like '../../article/article.entity'. When you do a production build like this, it moves all your files into a folder called 'dist' which does not contain a 'src' folder in it, which is why it says it can't find that file when you try to run your production build.

Comment: Important addition: the default .gitignore includes the /dist folder. This needs to be removed in order for the heroku deploy to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new NestJS project via `nest new project-name` it will come with the needed scripts in `package.json`.

```sh
yarn build
yarn start:prod
```

The rest depends on where you want to host the app. NestJS will run on any generic-purpose hosting (Heroku, Vercel, AWS, etc).

If you want to get started with low-config and for free you could try Heroku with the following Dockerized setup:

`Dockerfile.prod`

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . /app

RUN yarn build
```

`heroku.yml`

```yaml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile.prod
run:
  web: yarn start:prod
```

Once the app is created run

```sh
heroku git:remote --app <app-name>
heroku stack:set container
```

In your `bootstrap` function (`main.ts`) use the `PORT` env var:

```js
await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

If you're using a DB you have to set that up as well.